# unable to apply styles to dynamically added elements

Tags: jquery, css

below is my code and style is not applied for some reason.may be i am doing some mistake. i 
just added the li dynamically.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<style >
    #menu ul{
        background: red;          
    }
    #menu ul li{
        float: left;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        var arr = new Array("file", "edit");
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            localStorage.setItem(i, arr[i]);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            $("#menu").append("<li>" + localStorage.getItem(i) + "</li>");
        }

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="menu" class="menu"></ul>


</body>
</html>
```

Let me make it clear that I dont want to add css dynamically. because i expect lot of css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Menu is the `ul` element

```
#menu {
    background: red;
}
#menu li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4e8CY/)

Answer (score 0):

`#menu` is the UL

```
#menu li{
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

`#menu ul li` matched an UL inside the #menu UL etc

Answer (score 0):

`ul` has `id="menu"` you so should declare style like this.

```
  ul#menu li{
            float: left;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`#menu` is the id of `ul` so target their `li`

Try this

```
 #menu li{
        float: left;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2EcWH/3/

```
 ul {
     background: red;
    float: left;
 }
 #menu.li {
     list-style-type: none;
 }
```